# Why is it discouraged to accept a reference &String, &Vec, or &Box as a function argument?

Tags: rust

I wrote some Rust code that takes a `&String` as an argument:

```
fn awesome_greeting(name: &String) {
    println!("Wow, you are awesome, {}!", name);
}
```

I've also written code that takes in a reference to a `Vec` or `Box`:

```
fn total_price(prices: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    prices.iter().sum()
}

fn is_even(value: &Box<i32>) -> bool {
    **value % 2 == 0
}
```

However, I received some feedback that doing it like this isn't a good idea. Why not?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

**TL;DR: One can instead use `&str`, `&[T]` or `&T` to allow for more generic code.**

---

1. One of the main reasons to use a `String` or a `Vec` is because they allow increasing or decreasing the capacity. However, when you accept an immutable reference, you cannot use any of those interesting methods on the `Vec` or `String`.
2. Accepting a `&String`, `&Vec` or `&Box` also **requires** the argument to be allocated on the heap before you can call the function. Accepting a `&str` allows a string literal (saved in the program data) and accepting a `&[T]` or `&T` allows a stack-allocated array or variable. Unnecessary allocation is a performance loss. This is usually exposed right away when you try to call these methods in a test or a `main` method:

   ```
   awesome_greeting(&String::from("Anna"));
   ```

   ```
   total_price(&vec![42, 13, 1337])
   ```

   ```
   is_even(&Box::new(42))
   ```
3. Another performance consideration is that `&String`, `&Vec` and `&Box` introduce an unnecessary layer of indirection as you have to dereference the `&String` to get a `String` and then perform a second dereference to end up at `&str`.

Instead, you should accept a *string slice* (`&str`), a *slice* (`&[T]`), or just a reference (`&T`). A `&String`, `&Vec<T>` or `&Box<T>` will be automatically coerced (via [*deref coercion*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types)) to a `&str`, `&[T]` or `&T`, respectively.

```
fn awesome_greeting(name: &str) {
    println!("Wow, you are awesome, {}!", name);
}
```

```
fn total_price(prices: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    prices.iter().sum()
}
```

```
fn is_even(value: &i32) -> bool {
    *value % 2 == 0
}
```

Now you can call these methods with a broader set of types. For example, `awesome_greeting` can be called with a string literal (`"Anna"`) *or* an allocated `String`. `total_price` can be called with a reference to an array (`&[1, 2, 3]`) *or* an allocated `Vec`.

---

If you'd like to add or remove items from the `String` or `Vec<T>`, you can take a *mutable reference* (`&mut String` or `&mut Vec<T>`):

```
fn add_greeting_target(greeting: &mut String) {
    greeting.push_str("world!");
}
```

```
fn add_candy_prices(prices: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    prices.push(5);
    prices.push(25);
}
```

Specifically for slices, you can also accept a `&mut [T]` or `&mut str`. This allows you to mutate a specific value inside the slice, but you cannot change the number of items inside the slice (which means it's very restricted for strings):

```
fn reset_first_price(prices: &mut [i32]) {
    prices[0] = 0;
}
```

```
fn lowercase_first_ascii_character(s: &mut str) {
    if let Some(f) = s.get_mut(0..1) {
        f.make_ascii_lowercase();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a **tl;dr** in the beginning? This answer is already somewhat long. Something like "`&str` is more general (as in: imposes less restrictions) without reduced capabilities"? Also: point 3 is often not that important I think. Usually `Vec`s and `String`s will live on the stack and often even somewhere near the current stack frame. The stack is usually hot and the dereference will be served from a CPU cache.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Regarding the allocation cost, it might be worth mentioning the particular issue of substrings/slices when talking about mandatory allocation. `total_price(&prices[0..4])` does not require allocating a new vector for the slice.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm just getting started in Rust and was getting tied up figuring out when I should use a `&str` and *why* (coming from Python, so I usually don't explicitly deal with types). Cleared all of that up perfectly

Comment: Awesome tips on parameters. Just need one doubt: *"Accepting a &String, &Vec or &Box also requires an allocation before you can call the method. "* ... Why is that so? Could you please point out the part in the docs where I can read this in detail? (I'm a begginner). Also, can we have similar tips on the return types?

Comment: @Nawaz [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) — "for heap allocation". [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) — "This buffer is always stored on the heap". [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) — "the memory it points to is on the heap"

Comment: I'm missing information about why extra allocation is required. String is stored on the heap, when accepting &String as argument, why doesn't just Rust pass a pointer stored on the stack that points to the heap space, I don't understand why passing a &String would need additional allocation, passing a string slice should also require sending a pointer stored on the stack that points to the heap space?

Comment: @cjohansson the storage on the heap that you mention *is* the extra allocation. The reference itself is passed as you describe. `awesome_greeting(&String::from(“Anna”))` has an unneeded allocation from creating the string at all; `awesome_greeting(“Anna”)` does not. A string literal like that is not stored on the heap at all.

Comment: It is probably easier to understand on the heap allocation part that, Vec and String can dynamically change their contents (size) at runtime, therefore are (almost) impossible to allocate on the stack; and Box is designed for heap allocation. So for function parameter types, it is better to use compatible types for them while not having the implication of mandatory heap allocation.

Comment: For completeness, it should be noted that the only time it makes sense to accept `&String` or `&Vec` is when you need access to `&self`-taking methods that only exist on those, namely `capacity`.

Furthermore, none of this applies to *mutable* borrows, ie `&mut Vec` or `&mut String`, which are legitimately needed when you want to grow or shrink the collection.

Answer (score 56):

In addition to [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40006220/493729), another reason to accept a `&str` (and similarly `&[T]` etc) is because of all of the other types *besides* `String` and `&str` that also satisfy `Deref<Target = str>`. One of the most notable examples is `Cow<str>`, which lets you be very flexible about whether you are dealing with owned or borrowed data.

If you have:

```
fn awesome_greeting(name: &String) {
    println!("Wow, you are awesome, {}!", name);
}
```

But you need to call it with a `Cow<str>`, you'll have to do this:

```
let c: Cow<str> = Cow::from("hello");
// Allocate an owned String from a str reference and then makes a reference to it anyway!
awesome_greeting(&c.to_string());
```

When you change the argument type to `&str`, you can use `Cow` seamlessly, without any unnecessary allocation, just like with `String`:

```
let c: Cow<str> = Cow::from("hello");
// Just pass the same reference along
awesome_greeting(&c);

let c: Cow<str> = Cow::from(String::from("hello"));
// Pass a reference to the owned string that you already have
awesome_greeting(&c);
```

Accepting `&str` makes calling your function more uniform and convenient, and the "easiest" way is now also the most efficient. These examples will also work with `Cow<[T]>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce code duplication and allow reuse.

The recommendation is using `&str` over `&String` because `&str` also satisfies `&String` or other types that borrows underlying utf-8 values. This makes the function usable for both owned strings and the string slices but not the other way around:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn greeting_one(name: &String) {
    println!("Wow, you are awesome, {}!", name);
}

fn greeting_two(name: &str) {
    println!("Wow, you are awesome, {}!", name);
}

fn main() {
    let s1 = "John Doe".to_string();
    let s2 = "Jenny Doe";
    let s3 = Cow::Borrowed("Sally Doe");
    let s4 = Cow::Owned("Sally Doe".to_string());

    greeting_one(&s1);
    // greeting_one(&s2);  // Does not compile
    // greeting_one(&s3);  // Does not compile
    greeting_one(&s4);
    
    greeting_two(&s1);
    greeting_two(s2);
    greeting_two(&s3);
    greeting_two(&s4);
}
```

Using vectors to manipulate text is never a good idea and does not even deserve discussion because you will loose all the sanity checks and performance optimizations the compiler provides.

String type uses vector internally anyway. Remember, Rust uses UTF-8 for strings for storage efficiency. If you use vector, you have to repeat all the hard work. Other than that, borrowing vectors or boxed values should be OK.

All these explanation becomes more clear if you understand the distinction between different string types.

[What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str/63874387#63874387)

Answer (score 0):

Because those types can be coerced, so if we use those types functions will accept less types:

1- a reference to String can be coerced to a str slice. For example create a function:

```
fn count_wovels(words:&String)->usize{
    let wovels_count=words.chars().into_iter().filter(|x|(*x=='a') | (*x=='e')| (*x=='i')| (*x=='o')|(*x=='u')).count();
    wovels_count
}
```

if you pass `&str`, it will not be accepted:

```
let name="yilmaz".to_string();
println!("{}",count_wovels(&name));
// this is not allowed because argument should be &String but we are passing str
// println!("{}",wovels("yilmaz"))
```

But if that function accepts `&str` instead

```
// words:&str
fn count_wovels(words:&str)->usize{ ... }
```

we can pass both types to the function

```
let name="yilmaz".to_string();
println!("{}",count_wovels(&name));
println!("{}",wovels("yilmaz"))
```

With this, our function can accept more types

2- Similary, a reference to Box `&Box[T]`, will be coerced to the reference to the value inside the Box `Box[&T]`. for example

```
fn length(name:&Box<&str>){
    println!("lenght  {}",name.len())
}
```

this accepts only `&Box<&str>` type

```
let boxed_str=Box::new("Hello");
length(&boxed_str);

// expected reference `&Box<&str>` found reference `&'static str`
// length("hello")
```

If we pass `&str` as type, we can pass both types

3- Similar relation exists between ref to a Vec and ref to an array

```
fn square(nums:&Vec<i32>){
    for num in nums{
        println!("square of {} is {}",num,num*num)
    }
}
fn main(){
    let nums=vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let nums_array=[1,2,3,4,5];
    // only &Vec<i32> is accepted
    square(&nums);
    // mismatched types: mismatched types expected reference `&Vec<i32>` found reference `&[{integer}; 5]`
    //square(&nums_array)
}
```

this will work for both types

```
fn square(nums:&[i32]){..}
```